# Embedded Youtube movie to be opened in its channel on Youtube

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-channels

I am embedding in my site a movie from my channel, using frame:

```
<iframe width="560" scrolling="auto" height="349" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Vc5ppNtdYjI?rel=0"></iframe>
```

When users click on the movie, it opens up in Youtube, but not in the context of its channel:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vc5ppNtdYjI&feature=player_embedded

I want it to open in its channel:
http://www.youtube.com/user/IsraelSciTech#p/a/u/0/Vc5ppNtdYjI

Is there an attribute I can add to the iframe tag, that will tell it to open in the channel?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @ngen - No, I haven't found a solution